# How to handle the 'LOC_NAME' element value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xquery

In the below example we are trying to handle value of 'LOC_NAME' element, If 'Front' word are coming in the end then we are removing using xslt 1.0:

Can anyone help.

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<LOC_NAME>Front</LOC_NAME>
<LOC_NAME>Arapaoa Front.</LOC_NAME>
<LOC_NAME>Arapaoa Island. Front</LOC_NAME>
<LOC_NAME>North Stake Front Stbd No.31</LOC_NAME>
<LOC_NAME>North Stake No.35</LOC_NAME>
</root>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<LOC_NAME>Front</LOC_NAME>
<LOC_NAME>Arapaoa</LOC_NAME>
<LOC_NAME>Arapaoa Island.</LOC_NAME>
<LOC_NAME>North Stake Front Stbd No.31</LOC_NAME>
<LOC_NAME>North Stake No.35</LOC_NAME>
</root>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LOC_NAME">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=".='Front'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'Front'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:copy>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Reference URL #** http://xsltransform.net/6qCcddQ/1

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Sorry for that, and Its pleasure for me to suggest me the answer which is very helpfull for me.

Comment: You need to clarify exactly which elements to modify .`"Front"` is not the same as `"Front."`. Can there be any other variants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you show could be achieved using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="LOC_NAME">
            <xsl:variable name="len" select="string-length(.)" />
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="substring(., $len - 5)=' Front'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, $len - 6)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="substring(., $len - 6)=' Front.'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, $len - 7)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, suggested solution working fine.